# Not understanding error messages about a class declaration and usage with List objects

Tags: c++, c++builder

I am writing a VCL application for Windows. In the process of learning more about C++ and using more modern techniques, I have converted the following structures into a usable class (I think) and an ordered list by using `TObjectList`.

These are the old structure declaration I converted:

```cpp
typedef struct chord {
    char cKey[6];
    char cRank[30];
    int  cFret;
    char cPos[40];
    char cPlay[6];
} CHORD;

typedef struct double_list {
  char   *key;
  int    element_marked;
  CHORD  *data;
  struct double_list *next;
  struct double_list *prior;
} DLIST;
```

When I compile the code as shown below, I received the following error messages for the global variable declarations, and I don't understand either.

```
TObjectList<Chord> chordList;
Chord chordObj;

[bcc32c Error] Unit1.h(38): expected unqualified-id
[bcc32c Error] Unit1.h(39): must use 'class' tag to refer to type 'Chord' in this scope
  wingdi.h(3740): class 'Chord' is hidden by a non-type declaration of 'Chord' here
```

I have tried to declare the `TObjectList` and `Chord` both inside and outside of the `TForm1` class. Each way it generates different error messages. Should I be using `TList` versus `TObjectList`, or some other version of a List object, given there will be hundreds of `Chord` objects in the list?

I'm completely stumped. Any clarification of what is going on, and best practices and methods to use, would be greatly appreciated.

Here is the header file:

```cpp
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------

#ifndef Unit1H
#define Unit1H
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
#include <System.Classes.hpp>
#include <System.Contnrs.hpp>
#include <Vcl.Controls.hpp>
#include <Vcl.StdCtrls.hpp>
#include <Vcl.Forms.hpp>
#include <string>

//---------------------------------------------------------------------------

typedef std::string string;

class Chord {
private:
protected:
public:
    string searchKey;
    string cKey;
    string cRank;
    int    cFret;
    string cPos;
    string cPlay;

    Chord() {}
    Chord(string ck,string cr,int cf,string cp,string csp) {
        cKey=ck;
        cRank=cr;
        cFret=cf;
        cPos=cp;
        cPlay=csp;
    }
};

TObjectList<Chord> chordList;
Chord chordObj;

//---------------------------------------------------------------------------

class TForm1 : public TForm
{
__published:    // IDE-managed Components
private:    // User declarations
public:     // User declarations

    __fastcall TForm1(TComponent* Owner);

};

//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
extern PACKAGE TForm1 *Form1;
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
#endif
```

Here is the cpp file:

```cpp
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------

#include <vcl.h>
#pragma hdrstop

#include "Unit1.h"
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
#pragma package(smart_init)
#pragma resource "*.dfm"
TForm1 *Form1;
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
__fastcall TForm1::TForm1(TComponent* Owner)
    : TForm(Owner)
{
}
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: Unrelated: Do **not** do `typedef std::string string;`.  Do `using std::string;` - but never do that in the global namespace in header files.

Comment: What's at `wingdi.h(3740)`? Could it be a collision of names? You could put your `Chord` in a namespace - or try to change name to something else and see if that helps.

Comment: Seems like some other library (namely, `wingdi.h`, indirectly included by one of libraries that you use) already define _something_ called `Chord`. Not a type, though, maybe a variable or a function. I'd suggest either putting your `Chord` into your own namespace or renaming in other way.

Comment: By changing the class name from ```Chord``` to ```Chord1``` cleared up the second error, but not the first?

Comment: [Chord is function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/wingdi/nf-wingdi-chord?f1url=%3FappId%3DDev16IDEF1%26l%3DEN-US%26k%3Dk(WINGDI%252FChord)%3Bk(Chord)%3Bk(DevLang-C%252B%252B)%3Bk(TargetOS-Windows)%26rd%3Dtrue) defined by Windows.

Comment: @Pete Becker I think you are confused. The structures I show at the beginning are what I converted into the class ```Chord``` and was setting up to use ```TObjectList``` as shown in the header file. I have resolved the second error, but the first one remains.

Comment: Based on the first error message what would an "unqualified-id" be if its not the ```Chord``` or revised ```Chord1``` class?

Comment: @Ripi2 Search under "Main Help" and enter ```TObjectList``` it shows under "System.Contnrs.TObjectList"  and is defined as 

```class PASCALIMPLEMENTATION TObjectList : public System::Classes::TList```

Comment: Yeah, but I can't see a constructor using a template. My VCL knowledge is very limited.

Comment: @Ripi2 its under System.Generics.Collections  ```template<typename T> class PASCALIMPLEMENTATION TObjectList__1 : public TList__1<T>```

Comment: The generic version requires a diferent header to be included `System.Generics.Collections.hpp`

Comment: On a side note: because `TObjectList` derives from Delphi's `TObject` class, it MUST be constructed via the `new` operator in C++, declaring it like `TObjectList<Chord> chordList;` will simply not work (you should be getting [error E2459](https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/E2459_Delphi_style_classes_must_be_constructed_using_operator_new_(C%2B%2B)) about that). However, `Chord` does not exist in Delphi, so you can't store `Chord` objects in `TObjectList` to begin with, unless you add a Delphi `.pas` file to your C++ project and instantiate `TObjectList<Chord>` in the `.pas` file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Regarding

```
[bcc32c Error] Unit1.h(38): expected unqualified-id
```

Then include the file that is defining `TObjectList` according to [the documentation](https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Alexandria/en/System.Generics.Collections.TObjectList):

```cpp
#include <System.Generics.Collections.hpp>
```

and don't give it a template parameter and allocate it with `new` as is common for most `VCL` classes:

```
auto chordList = new TObjectList;
```

You could store the raw owning pointer in a `std::unique_ptr<TObjectList>` to not have to manually `delete` it later.

**Note:** However, `Chord` is not derived from `System::TObject` so using `TObjectList` for storing `Chord`s is not going to work (unless you make `Chord` inherit from `TObject`). That is because `TObjectList` stores `TObject*`.  I suggest using a `std::vector<Chord>` instead.

---

Regarding:

```
[bcc32c Error] Unit1.h(39): must use 'class' tag to refer to type 'Chord' in this scope
  wingdi.h(3740): class 'Chord' is hidden by a non-type declaration of 'Chord' here
```

In `wingdi.h`, line 3740, you'll find this declaration in the global namespace:

```cpp
WINGDIAPI BOOL WINAPI Chord( _In_ HDC hdc, _In_ int x1, _In_ int y1, _In_ int x2, _In_ int y2, _In_ int x3, _In_ int y3, _In_ int x4, _In_ int y4);
```

Your class `Chord` collides with this [`Chord` function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/wingdi/nf-wingdi-chord?f1url=%3FappId%3DDev16IDEF1%26l%3DEN-US%26k%3Dk(WINGDI%252FChord)%3Bk(Chord)%3Bk(DevLang-C%252B%252B)%3Bk(TargetOS-Windows)%26rd%3Dtrue), so you need to rename the class or put it in a namespace.

Another option could be to refer to the class by adding `class` first:

```cpp
class Chord chordObj;
```

but, that would be a rather non-idiomatic solution.

Comment: The compiler is expecting a "unqualified-id" for the ```TObjectList<Chord1> chordList;```. I tried to add the ```class``` and there was no change to the error.

Comment: @Skypilot65 Updated. Please see the note I made. `TObjectList` is not the proper container.

Comment: I updated the include file accordingly and changed the ```TObjectList chordList;``` and it now has the error ```Delphi style classes must be allocated with 'new'``` so I tried ```TObjectlist = new(Chord1);``` and it again needs an "unqualified-id" at the equal sign.

Comment: Ok. Back to learn about ```std:vector``` instead. Thanks!

Comment: @TedLyngmo Note that `auto chordList = new TObjectList;` will instantiate the non-templated `TObjectList` that is declared in `<System.Contnrs.hpp>`.  To use the templated `TObjectList` in `<System.Generics.Collections.hpp>`, you need to use `TObjectList__1` instead and give it a template parameter.

Comment: @Skypilot65 the correct way to instantiate `TObjectList<...>` via `new` is like this: `TObjectList_1<...> *chordList = new TObjectList_1<...>;` But as noted, since `Chord` is not derived from `TObject`, `TObjectList` is the wrong container for the job to begin with.

Comment: @RemyLebeau I gave `TObjectList__1` a shot when I wrote the answer and `new TObjectList__1<Chord>` compiled - but failed linking, because (I assume) this template is explicitly instantiated for specific types (maybe only `TObject`?) in the implementation files. If that's the case, of what use is the templated version? `TObjectList__1` doesn't really look like it belongs in usercode either :-)

Comment: @TedLyngmo it fails to link because of an issue that is described in the documentation: [How to Handle Delphi Generics in C++](https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/How_to_Handle_Delphi_Generics_in_C%2B%2B) (near the bottom): "*If C++ code attempts to use a Delphi generic for types that were not instantiated in Delphi, you'll get errors at link time.*" `Chord` is not a type that is being instantiated in Delphi, hence the failure.

Comment: @RemyLebeau Ah, sounds like I was pretty spot on then.